# Issue Converting Pixel Padding To Percent

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm looking to convert the padding: 10px 15px into percentages but when I do, the document area ends up becoming a lot smaller and is completely wrong.

I'm not sure if I'm calculating it incorrect, document area is 40px wide and I want a 15px padding either side so I would do 15/40 * 100?

Here is my first JSfiddle before I change the padding http://jsfiddle.net/ezaj4o4o/

```
<header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="main-logo"><a href="#">Name</a></h1>

    <h2 class="main-sub">Sub-Header</h2>

<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">About</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</header>

.main-logo {
margin: 0;
}
.main-nav {
text-align: center;
}
.main-nav li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 5%;
}
.main-logo a, .main-nav a {
display: block;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px 15px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.main-logo a {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 1.75em;
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
background-color: #333;
color: #ffffff;
}
.main-sub {
text-align:center;
}
```

Here is the JSfiddle after my calculation and 37.5% doesn't seem correct. See how its changed the document area?

http://jsfiddle.net/a12xakka/

Thank you.

Comment: Padding makes the object grow, unless you use `box-sizing`. So in your case this will never work, because the box is already growing and needs to be redrawn after the padding is added. It could never grow when it can never end rendering the desired calculated size.

Comment: So it won't be possible? I do have * {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
Set but I still get this issue, so would be okay to stick width px even though I need a responsive site?

Comment: I would never let padding scale. Let the content-boxes itself scale. Padding would likely only change based on a media-query. You could say like give me a huge spacy padding on Desktop-media, but when the size reaches Tablet-media or smaller, change to a much smaller Padding. This is often common practice and make your design much smoother and calmer to look at. If everything in your design constantly shifts and reshapes on window-resize it will be very disturbing for the user.

Comment: Thank you for the insight so should I drop the padding altogether?, so how would I get the navigation boxes to have a decent sized clickable area on hover?